# Trivy using HTML templates

Tags: trivy

Im running Trivy v0.49.1 from `brew install trivy` and I want to have my output formatted into a HTML file. The [docs here](https://aquasecurity.github.io/trivy/v0.17.2/examples/report/#html)  say to run `trivy image --format template --template "@contrib/html.tpl" -o report.html golang:1.12-alpine` however, the resulting file only shows the text "html.tpl" and show no results.

When running locally I downloaded and pointed to this template `html.tpl` from their [GitHub page here](https://github.com/aquasecurity/trivy/blob/main/contrib/html.tpl)

Is there a reason why `trivy config . --format template --template "html.tpl" -o report.html` would fail to show findings when `trivy config . --format json` outputs results? It seems like the HTML file they provide is out of date or no longer works with the latest version?

Running with a `--debug` flag shows its finding results just not outputting them to the file. `2024-03-13T14:40:36.723Z DEBUG   [misconf] 40:36.723172000 terraform.executor`

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, you have to prepend an `@` to the file path.

- html.tpl -> @html.tpl
- templates/html.tpl -> @templates/html.tpl